# How to validate three separate fields as a date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate a date that is separated into three fields (year, month, and day, of course). I cannot change these fields, as much as I'd like to. I am using the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) (also not by my choice). I cannot figure how to validate all three fields as one. Even validating them individually would suffice.

My HTML is as follows.

```html
<div class="date-field requiredField">
    <div class="date-picker hasDatepicker" id="dp1412187717156" style="display: none;">...</div>
    <input type="text" class="month" required="required" maxlength="2" placeholder="MM" title="Month" value="1">
    &nbsp;/&nbsp;
    <input type="text" class="day" required="required" maxlength="2" placeholder="DD" title="Day" value="1">
    &nbsp;/&nbsp;
    <input type="text" class="year" required="required" placeholder="YYYY" title="Year" value="1973">
    &nbsp;
    <span class="date-pick-button"></span>
    <span class="date-clear-button"></span>
</div>
```

I am invoking the validator as follows:

```
$("#SignUp_Enrollment").validate({
    focusInvalid : false,
    rules: {
        co_ssn: {
            ssn: true
        },
        first_name: {
            required: true
        },
        last_name: {
            required: true
        }
        // some more rules
    },
    invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
        // style the invalid fields
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

I am of course validating other fields, but this plugin is not showing me any mercy. I've tried adding month, day, and year rules to no avail. Any suggestions on what direction to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"Even validating them individually would suffice."*

Your code is broken because none of the fields in your HTML markup contain a `name` attribute.  A unique `name` is mandatory in order for this plugin to operate.  It's how it keeps track of the input elements.

See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#markup-recommendations

It's not shown in your markup, but all relevant input elements must also be contained within `<form></form>` tags.  This plugin will not work otherwise.

---

Since you already have the date saved into an hidden field, you can also just validate the hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="myDate" />
```

Activate validation on hidden fields by using the `ignore: []` option.

Then as long as this hidden field has a unique `name` attribute, you can apply validation rules the same as you would on any other field.

Use the `errorPlacement` callback to precisely place the message attached to the hidden field.

Comment: @TylerCrompton, my answer is still valid.

Answer (score -1):

You can merge this three fields to one (`hidden` input), and validate this input

```
var day, month, year;

day = $('.day').val();
month = $('.month').val();
year = $('.year').val();

$('.hidden-date-input').val([day, year, month].join('-'));
```

Comment: I am actually already doing this, for sake of sending simple parameters to the server. But how do I validate a field that is hidden?

Comment: i assume just pass this input to validator. Try [valid](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid) method `$('.hidden-date-input').valid()`